# How can I allow scrolling of the background when the 'confirm' box pops up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Using a Chrome extension in the browser, I allow the user to select a bunch of text to submit to the database. When the user hits enter, a confirm box pops up, but before the user hits 'OK' to submit, I want the user to be able to scroll in the background and double check everything that he's submitting. Is there anyway to make the background scroll while the confirm window is in focus?

Comment: You need to use modal windows in that case instead of confirm box

Comment: You should pop up the user-entered fields in the confirmation window. That clears up any encoding issues too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the JQ dialog with **modal** set to **false**

Official doco on how it works is here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

Provided that the text/fields/data to be submitted isn't huge, you should also consider jasonscript's idea of presenting the data in the popup.  From what you're saying though, it's more important to show what they might have MISSED, not just what they included.  Perhaps an on the fly screenshot of the webpage at the point they opened the submission form?  That would show their selection clearly.

Comment: Pretty sure hes using the dom confirm which is always modal.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I'm new here and saw it was tagged to jquery so I just presumed :\ sorry bout that!  To prepend() my answer, use jquery's dialog() function as you are likely already using it and it is purpose-built for exactly this type of use!